# oracle query optimization issue

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

Is there any way to optimize the query below?

```
SELECT RNC,
       CELLNAME,
       SUM(C310484605) AS DL_PWR_FAIL,
       SUM(C310484607) AS UL_PWR_FAIL,
       SUM(C310484609) AS HSDPA_FAIL,
       SUM(C310484611) AS HSUPA_FAIL
FROM ZTE_UTRAN.UCELLCAP1
WHERE CELLNAME LIKE '_____B%'
  AND DATETIME >=TRUNC(SYSDATE)-7
GROUP BY RNC,
         CELLNAME
ORDER BY HSDPA_FAIL DESC
```

it's taking like hours in execution. Function "sum" is slowing it down but i don't know how to fix it.
Any help would be appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: Not related, but you can use `substr(CELLNAME,5,1) = 'B'` instead of `CELLNAME like '_____B%'` please adjust the position in substr according to requirement

Comment: yes you are right but "like" is not affecting the speed of query but "SUM" is. even if i comment CELLNAME like '_____B%' condition it's taking hours. so issue is with "SUM"

Comment: @Dharmendra It is unlikely that `SUM` is responsible for performance issues.  The vast majority of performance issues are caused by retrieving data and joining it.  The time spent in small functions like `SUM` is usually irrelevant.  How large is the table `UCELLCAP1`?  Do any of the predicates filter out a large percentage of the data?  If so, they might be a good candidate for an index.

Comment: The expression suggested by @Tejash could also be used to create an index that might help performance (which is not the case with the LIKE condition)

Answer (score 1):

There could not be a concrete answer by just looking at query.

- you should chech execution plan of query, which shows how database will be executing the query and where most of the time is spent.
- then based on results, you may want to have indexes on columns used in "group by" or have a partitions etc

General observations-

1. Even if you have index on CELL_NAME column, there is no benefit as you are using like predicate where start is not constant. If its something like (a like "ab*") then index would be helpful.
2. Add index on group by columns.

Comment: hi thanks for the answer but as i tried to check group by is not creating issue here. it's "SUM" which is slowing it down. is there anything else i can do for "SUM"??

Comment: You need to determine where time is being spent. As has been said earlier, SUM() is unlikely to be the culprit, unless you can provide diagnostics to show otherwise. I would suggest getting a SQL Monitor report.

Comment: Try removing all the sum functions from select then and see what's the time. Next Instead of sum just use count function.